# Android Theming/Colors: Accent color completely invisible when setting a primary color

Tags: android, styles, material-design

A bit of overview on my app: I'm using the Google Material Components library, so my app theme has the parent `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`.

The issue I'm having is with the colors of my theme. The main place that this is a problem is in a DialogFragment that I've defined. If I declare my theme like this, with explicit primary, primaryDark, and accent colors set:

```
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorDarkPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorDarkPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorDarkAccent</item>
</style>
```

then the buttons of my DialogFragment are completely invisible (they should be colorAccent): [image]

If I comment all of the color declarations out of the theme, then the buttons do appear:
[image]

The problem is of course I want to be able to define my own colors. I've tried just defining a `colorPrimary` and not defining `colorPrimaryDark` and `colorAccent`, but this leads to the same problem of the accent text being completely invisible for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm leaving this up so others can find it, but the answer as always lies in the documentation.

Inheriting any `Theme.MaterialComponents` changes the names that you have to give colors. Instead of `colorAccent` as it is with default Android themes, you have to use `colorSecondary`.

See:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md

That's half the problem. The other half is that, when using MaterialComponents, it's best to use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`. So I switched my dialog builder to be defined like this:

```
val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(it, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
```

The final step is the `R.style.AlertDialogTheme` declaration. In styles.xml, I defined that theme to style alert dialogs, and it looks like this:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/AlertButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/AlertButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/AlertButton</item>
</style>
```

All that `@style/AlertButton` does is set the text color to the color we are after:

```
<style name="AlertButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorDarkAccent</item>
</style>
```

And finally, the dialog buttons use the color you want.

Comment: with the `MaterialAlertDialog` you should use `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog` as parent and the button style should inherits from `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog`